# php breadcrumbs DO NOT display them on specific pages

Tags: php, html, breadcrumbs

I have a html project, with various template files. I want to display breadcrumbs, in all pages except on index.php and contact.php. 
I have the breadcrumbs working; what I can't get it to work is the condition for only displaying it if the pages are not index.php or contact.php:

So far, I know I could do this if it was in the other way around, only display it on those pages:

```
 $noBreadcrumbs = array("index.php", "contact.php");
    foreach ($noBreadcrumbs as $page => $pageName) {
      if (stripos(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), $pageName)){
      echo '<div class="breadcrumbs container">';
          require ("breadcrumbs.php");
          echo '</div>';
    }
  }
```

But because it has to be in the other way around.... I don't know how to do it! If I echo de request uri it appears also with the project name (thousand_motors/index.php), and.... I am stuck. I can't print only "index.php" and even if so, I don't know how can I do the foreach but when they are not those pages...

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
if (!stripos( //....
```

Comment: can you believe I didn't try it???? U____U I was trying == NULL, == FALSE..... ! in_array.... and my mind didn't think in the easiest way.... great. It works as expected now. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. It happens after some hours of coding :)